# jquery appply for only first fetched item

Tags: php, jquery

code display database data & i want to hide "minusbtn" for quantity=1 and show anchor tag and when it increments again both will show. Jquery works for only first fetched database item so guide me please what will change in jquery so that it will works for all item fetched from database.

```
<?php        
    //Get all these items
    $query = mysql_query("select * from products_added where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["REMOTE_ADDR"])."'");
    ?>
    <?php
    //Fetch all added items and display to the screen for the specified user
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $item_id = $row["id"];
        $item_name = $row["item_added"];
        $price = $row["price"];
        $quantity = $row["quantity"];
        $amount = $row["amount"];
        $date = $row["date"];
        ?>
        <div id="items_cover<?php echo $item_id;?>">
            <dl class="row order-item-total"  >
                <dt class="col-sm-2 text-weight-light text-right"><?php echo $item_name; ?></dt>
                <dd class="col-sm-8 tempptr">
                    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' id="minusbtn" field='quantity' data-id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" data-value="<?php echo $row['price'];?>"/>
                    <input type='text' name='quantity' id="qty" value="<?php echo $quantity ;?>" class='qty' data-value="<?php echo $quantity ;?>"/>
                    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' id="plusbtn"  field='quantity' data-id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" data-value="<?php echo $row['price'];?>"/> X <?php echo $row['price'];?>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" id="amount1">
                </dd>
                <dd class="col-sm-2 text-spl-color text-right totalamt" id="totalamt">Rs.<?php echo $amount; ?></dd>
                <dd class="col-sm-1">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="width:10px; height:10px; padding:3px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px; text-decoration:none;" id="vpb_cart_buttons" title="Remove this item" onclick="vpb_remove_this_item('<?php echo $item_id; ?>');">X</a>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

jquery which apply only for first div only plz suggest solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var qty=$('.qty').attr('data-value');
    if(qty==1){
        $("#vpb_cart_buttons").hide();
    }else{
       $("#vpb_cart_buttons").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using same ID's of HTML elements in while loop. This causes repeated ID's whereas according to the rule, ID should be unique on a page.
JQuery therefore picks the first matched ID only. Use classes for these purpose instead.